# How to read arbitrary length input from stdin properly?

Tags: c, buffer, fgets

I want to ask user to input some string in each loop.  However, the code below will skip loop multiple times if the length of input is greater than 2?

Why is this happening and what's the best way to read arbitrary length input from stdin?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char in[2];
    while (in[0] != 'q') {
        puts("Enter: ");
        fgets(in, 3, stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not `3`, but `2` for `fgets`. The buffer is only 2 large.

Comment: Can you show me some examples to this specific problem?

Comment: And no, this is not related to buffer overflow. It is just an incidental. And I don't know why anyone thought this is worth upvoting. Your problem is that `fgets` does not *skip* everything until the end of line if the line is longer than the buffer.

Comment: You are telling [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) that your buffer is large enough to hold 2 chars plus a null char (`'\0'`). But your buffer is only large enough to hold 1 char plus `'\0'`.

Comment: So, what happed when my input length exceed 2, why it will skip next loop's fgets, is there anything I can do?

Comment: When the input length exceeded 1, fgets attempted to write data beyond the bounds of the array.  The behavior of your program after that is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your buffer is not large enough to hold a 2 character string. Strings in C need to have an extra '\0' appended to them to mark the end. Second, `fgets` will leave chars in the input buffer when the input string is longer than the buffer passed to it. You need to consume those characters before calling `fgets` again.

Here is a function, similar to `fgets` in that it will only read `buffer_len - 1` chars. And it will also consume all chars until the newline or EOF.

```
int my_gets(char *buffer, size_t buffer_len)
{
    // Clear buffer to ensure the string will be null terminated
    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);

    int c;
    int bytes_read = 0;
    // Read one char at a time until EOF or newline
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(stdin)) && '\n' != c) {
        // Only add to buffer if within size limit
        if (bytes_read < buffer_len - 1) {
            buffer[bytes_read++] = (char)c;
        }
    }
    return bytes_read;
}

int main(void)
{
    char in[3];  // Large enough for a 2 char string

    // Re-arranged to do/while
    do {
        puts("Enter: ");
        my_gets(in, sizeof(in));  // sizeof(in) == 3
    } while (in[0] != 'q');
    return 0;
}
```